# Union of chains, does $(1,1,1,\ldots)\in \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+}B_i$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, logic

Define an infinite chain $B_i=\{(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_i,0,0,0,\ldots)|$ where $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_i$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}\}$ where $i\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Does $(1_1,1_2,1_3,\ldots)\in \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+}B_i$?

My argument was it doesn't since for every $i$, the tuple only had finite many $1$s, and $\omega$ was not in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What is $1_1$??

Comment: One at $a_1$, the identity of the first place, in this case $1_1=1$. I just wrote them to indicate order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to say is that $B_i$ is the set of all functions $\mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $B(k) = 0$ for all $k > i$. You want to know if $(j\mapsto 1)\in\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+}B_i$. $j \mapsto 1$ represents what you are writing as $(1,1,\dots)$. I strongly recommend thinking of "infinite tuples" as functions (that's what they are). This avoids needing to constantly use hand-wavy ellipses.

$f\in\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+}B_i$ if and only if $\exists i\in\mathbb{Z}^+.f\in B_i$. At which point, if $f(j) = 1$ for all $j$, i.e. $f = j\mapsto 1$, then there is no $k > i$ such that $f(k) = 0$, so there is no $i$ such that $f\in B_i$. So $(j\mapsto 1)\notin\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+}B_i$, or using your notation $(1,1,\dots)\notin\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+}B_i$.

More generally, I recommend thinking of sets (especially infinite sets) as more like "properties" than "collections". Asking if $x\in S$ is better thought of as asking if $x$ satisfies the property that characterizes elements of $S$ than whether it is "somewhere" in the "collection" of elements of $S$. In this example, the function $f$ defined as $f(j)=1$ does not satisfy the property $\exists i\in\mathbb{Z}^+.\forall k > i.f(k) = 0$ and so is not in $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}^+}B_i$.

Comment: Sorry, was typing in first-order logic, just corrected it. So $(1,1,...)$ was not in it? Then the chain would include all the tuple up to but not include infinite order?